# python csv linux urllib2

Tags: python, html, csv

I am loading the data from url to csv file, how can we load it correctly?
however, i got some python scripts to read the data but it is not loading the data,it is replacing the data within that file?

I am new to python so send me the documentation and also send me the code for getting and loading the data from html into csv file.

Advance in thanks.

Regards ,
V.Bhargava

Comment: Can you post the code that is replacing the data withing the file? How about a sample of what you download?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No problem:

- [`csv` library docs](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html)
- [`urllib2` library docs](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html)

For the second part, we would need to know what the data you're downloading looks like.

Comment: just i want to insert the data into database from that csv file , so can you help me